# Dataview vs ListView in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my current app, i am getting more than 40 records with images. In single record i have 6 fields to display include image field. Right now i am using Dataview to display the records whether **Dataview** will impact my app performance if i get more than 100 records from server ? or i should go for **Listview** ?

sample snipplet

```
 itemList:function(){
    return [
                "<tpl>",
                "<div class='Container'>",
                        "<div class='OfferImgContainer'><img class='offerImg' src={thumbnail}></div>",
                        "<p>",
                        "<div class='offerCategory'>{category}</div>",
                        "<div class='offerheader'>{title}</div>",
                        "<div class='offerContent1'> {content}</div>",
                        "<div class='offerContentfind'>Find out more <i class='offerArrow fa fa-chevron-right'></i></div>",

                "</tpl>"

            ];
},
```

Answer (score 1):

List does quite a bit more than DataView to support infinite dataset. List will render slower but during runtime with as many records in the store it will handle it a lot better. If you try to use DataView with a thousand records in the store, the device will struggle to handle that many DOM nodes so the List can handle this. If you don't need the features List brings to the table, then just use a DataView and style it the way you need it to look.

Answer (score 0):

ListView :

1. Can handle multiple records
2. Good support for basic listing

Dataview:

- Support others sencha components inside the dataview by extending **'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem'**
- Good to have less no of records in order to avoid performance issue